# copy retrived json data and paste into text editor in text format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, angular2-template

```js
collegeDestails = [
      {
        "name": "Indirabai Meghe Mahila Mahavidyalaya,Amravati.",
        "address": "Morshi Road Amravati. 444602",
        "phone": 9423424787,
        "district": "Amravati",
        "email": "imc.amt@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Indirabai Meghe Mahila Mahavidyalaya,Amravati.",
        "address": "Morshi Road Amravati. 444602",
        "phone": 9423424787,
        "district": "Amravati",
        "email": "imc.amt@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Indirabai Meghe Mahila Mahavidyalaya,Amravati.",
        "address": "Morshi Road Amravati. 444602",
        "phone": 9423424787,
        "district": "Amravati",
        "email": "imc.amt@gmail.com"
      },

      {
        "name": "Indirabai Meghe Mahila Mahavidyalaya,Amravati.",
        "address": "Morshi Road Amravati. 444602",
        "phone": 9423424787,
        "district": "Amravati",
        "email": "imc.amt@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Indirabai Meghe Mahila Mahavidyalaya,Amravati.",
        "address": "Morshi Road Amravati. 444602",
        "phone": 9423424787,
        "district": "Amravati",
        "email": "imc.amt@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Indirabai Meghe Mahila Mahavidyalaya,Amravati.",
        "address": "Morshi Road Amravati. 444602",
        "phone": 9423424787,
        "district": "Amravati",
        "email": "imc.amt@gmail.com"
      },

      {
        "name": "Indirabai Meghe Mahila Mahavidyalaya,Amravati.",
        "address": "Morshi Road Amravati. 444602",
        "phone": 9423424787,
        "district": "Amravati",
        "email": "imc.amt@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Indirabai Meghe Mahila Mahavidyalaya,Amravati.",
        "address": "Morshi Road Amravati. 444602",
        "phone": 9423424787,
        "district": "Amravati",
        "email": "imc.amt@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Indirabai Meghe Mahila Mahavidyalaya,Amravati.",
        "address": "Morshi Road Amravati. 444602",
        "phone": 9423424787,
        "district": "Amravati",
        "email": "imc.amt@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Indirabai Meghe Mahila Mahavidyalaya,Amravati.",
        "address": "Morshi Road Amravati. 444602",
        "phone": 9423424787,
        "district": "Amravati",
        "email": "imc.amt@gmail.com"
      }
    ]
```

```html
<div class="card" *ngFor="let data of collegeDestails;let i = index">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ data.name }}</span>
                    <div class="form-check float-right">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" (change)="instituteChecked($event,i)">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="details-section">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Address: </p>
                                <p>{{ data.address }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="details-section">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Phone: </p>
                                <p>{{ data.phone }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="details-section">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">District: </p>
                                <p>{{ data.district }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="details-section">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Email:</p>
                                <p>{{ data.email }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <hr> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am using angular 2, I want to implement one functionality that is I am getting a list of records from my server in JSON format. When the user selects more than one or one record using the checkbox & click on the copy button all record should be copied in text format he/she can paste in any text editor. how can I implement this feature? thank you in advance.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyCYg.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `copyToClipboard` method that would stringify your record and store them into the clipboard :

```
copyToClipboard(record:Record){
  let content = JSON.stringify(record);
  document.addEventListener('copy', (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', content);
    e.preventDefault();
    document.removeEventListener('copy');
  });
  document.execCommand('copy');
};
```